# Nested class Access methods for Properties in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, access-modifiers

I am trying to figure out the best approach for setting and getting properties in a nested class I am creating.

I have a class, Car which has a nested class ControlPanel and want to make the properties of the Control Panel only accessible to the Car and Control Panel  class.

(ie: not within the assembly or namespace and not within the application the class library will be going to be used)... I have changed the class access properties to friend, protected friend, private, public, but any combination is not matching my expected results.

I want to change the properties in the Drive() Sub of a class as shown below.

Any thoughts?

```
 Public Class Car

    Dim cp As New ControlPanel

    Public Class ControlPanel
      Private _Speedometer As Integer = 0
      Private _Odometer As Integer = 0

      Public Property Speedometer() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Speedometer
        End Get
        Protected Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Speedometer = value
        End Set
      End Property

      Public Property Odometer() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Odometer
        End Get
        Protected Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Odometer = value
        End Set
     End Property

    End Class

   Public Sub Drive()

        cp.Odometer = 76323
        co.Speedometer = 86

   End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Can you expand on your question? Do you want the *entire ControlPanel class* to be inaccessible, or do you want *only those two properties* to be inaccessible, from any class other than Car? Also, your code seems to suggest you want differing access for the getter and setter, but you don't state this clearly in the question.  Do you want different access for the getter and setter also?

Comment: Apologises for the confusion. What I would like to see is the ControlPanel to be readonly from outside the Car class, but Read/Write in the Car and Control Panel classes.

Comment: Based on that comment, what I think you are looking for is what I had suggested with a Private nested class that has a public (or friend) interface. That will ensure that the Car class can access all members on ControlPanel, but the outside would only hold on to a reference of IControlPanel that would only expose the gets. If something other than Car can insantiate the ControlPanel class, you may need some form of factory method (Create) that returns IControlPanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Public Class Car

  Private Interface IControlPanel
    Property Odometer As Integer
    Property Speedometer As Integer
  End Interface

  Public Class ControlPanel
    Implements IControlPanel
    Public ReadOnly Property Odometer As Integer
      Get
        Return CType(Me, IControlPanel).Odometer
      End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Speedometer As Integer
      Get
        Return CType(Me, IControlPanel).Speedometer
      End Get
    End Property
    Private Property IControlPanel_Odometer As Integer Implements IControlPanel.Odometer
    Private Property IControlPanel_Speedometer As Integer Implements IControlPanel.Speedometer
  End Class

  Dim cp As IControlPanel = New ControlPanel()

  Public Sub Drive()
    cp.Odometer = 76323
    cp.Speedometer = 86 
  End Sub

End Class
```

It uses a private interface nested in the `Car` class with privately implemented and aliased members in `ControlPanel`. This way, only `Car` can access the interface members.

Answer (score 4):

As Robert Levy pointed out, you are referring to a "Nested Class" and not a "Subclass" etc.

As for how to achieve what you are looking for... are you simply looking to make ControlPanel a private class? That will ensure that all members of ControlPanel are only accessible to Car. If you have other members on ControlPanel that need to be exposed, or the outside outside world needs to hold a reference to ControlPanel in someway, consider using an Interface to expose only those members that you want to be publically available.

```
Public Class Car

  Dim cp As New ControlPanel

  Private Class ControlPanel

    Public Property Speedometer As Integer
    Public Property Odometer As Integer

  End Class

  Public Sub Drive()
    cp.Odometer = 76323
    cp.Speedometer = 86
  End Sub

End Class
```

Optionally...

```
Friend Interface IControlPanel
  //Whatever actually needs to be publically accessible.    
End Interface

// Other Code...

Private Class ControlPanel
  Implements IControlPanel

// Other Code...
```

What is the goal that you are trying to achieve in terms of API?

Comment: The purpose I am trying to achieve is modularity. Instead of creating 100 properties at the Car level, I want to break the properies which relate to each other into these "folder" classes.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clarify terminology.  What you are talking about here is a "nested" class and not a subclass

I dont believe what you are trying to do is possible in .NET.  However, do you really need it?  If cp is private within Car, nobody can increment the odometer on that car's control panel. They could create their own controlpanel that isn't part of a car and then mess with it, but what's the harm in that?

Comment: I have made the ControlPanel Private, but a property in the Car class makes it avaliable. ie: (MyCar.ControlPanel.Odometer)

Answer (score 0):

Make your `ControlPanel` class private and its properties public.  The `ControlPanel` class will then only be visible to the `Car` type, but `Car` will still be able to modify `ControlPanel`'s properties.

Comment: The Control panel should still be publicly available as readonly outside the Car class. The Control panel should be abe to read/write to the ControlPanel.

Comment: The values for the Odometer and Speedometer are also placeholder values. These fields will be linked to a database and displayable upon request. (ie: MyCar.ControlPanel.Speedometer)

Answer (score 0):

nested classes is one way to go or you can have your Car as a composite class. Control panel can be used in many different cars (sub classes) so why make it nested? Car has a Control Panel. Car has an Engine

Bus : Car also has those things.

Radio might be something that Control Panel has. Speedometer could be part of Dashboard that can also be part of the Control Panel.

Then you end up with

MyCar.ItsControlPanel.Radio
MyCar.ItsControlPanel.Dashboard.Speedometer.CurrentSpeed;

How about Motorcycle? It isnt a car but it still has a Dashboard which has a Speedometer.

Get my point? Composite objects.